# Chartjs - tooltip - different corner radius

Tags: javascript, chart.js

As in documentation, to change cornerRadius of tooltips

```
       tooltips: {
          cornerRadius: 10
       }
```

But i need to change one corner in different way than the others ( like in css -> border-top-left-radius: 10px )
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu1Fn.png)

Is it even possible ?

Comment: As you pointed yourself, it can be done in CSS with something like `{
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}` (to follow the example of the picture you linked to). Why not doing it in CSS? Any specific reason?

Comment: If tooltip is not a canvas element, you can use pure css to do that.
Else I think you have to use `draw` method:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html

Answer (score -1):

ChartJS (actual version 3.5.0) doesn't offer a way to specify a different cornerRadius for every corners.  For setting different values for border radius of a tooltip you can [enable external tooltips](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips) in the global or chart configuration and use your custom CSS code for that purpose. Speaking about the native ChartJS code, I recently filed an issue on their GitHub repository to discuss the [implementation of this new feature](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/9533).  There you will find the code that allows the kind of functionality you are asking for. It involves changing just a few lines of code in a single function. Hope to have been of help for the community and for ChartJS users like you that need  a cornerRadius object

```
{topLeft: 50, topRight: 50, bottomLeft: 0, bottomRight: 0}
```

instead of a single value to customize the chart tooltip.